# Screen blanks and doesn't come back on, multiple distros

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, mx-linux

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 up until yesterday, with i3.  I had a problem where the screen would blank after some time (10 minutes?), and not un-blank in response to mouse/keyboard input.  The host was not sleeping: I could still ssh into it.

Yesterday I switched to MX Linux with xfce.  I disabled power management, screen blanking, and screensaver from the GUI settings tools.  The problem persists with this new install as well: the screen blanks after several minutes, and the keyboard/mouse won't un-blank it.  I can still ssh into it.

What might cause this, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Mx Linux icon, the double pyramids icon.  Then in the top of that window click in the search box, and type in xscreensaver.  Open it, and disable or configure your screensaver and screen time out, or when it considers the system idle, and turns the screensaver on.